# Speed up Django query

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, sqlperformance

I am working with Django to create a dashboard which present many kind of data. My problem is that the page loading slowly despite I hit the database (PostgreSql) always  once. These tables are loading with data in every 10th minute, so currently consist of millions of record. My problem is that when I make a query with Django ORM, I get the data slowly (according to the Django toolbar it is 1,4 second). I know that this not too much b is the half of the total loading time (3,1), so If I could decrease the time of the query the page loading could decrease to there for the user experience could be better. When the query run I fetch ~ 2800 rows. Is there any way to speed up this query? I do not know that I do something wrong or this time is normal with this amount of data. I attach my query and model. Thank you in advance for your help.

**My query (Here I fetch 6  hours time intervall.):**

```
  my_query=MyTable.filter(time_stamp__range=(before_now,  now)).values('time_stamp',  'value1', 'value2')
```

Here I tried to use .`iterator()` but the query wasn't faster.

**My model:**

```
class MyTable(models.Model):
        time_stamp = models.DateTimeField()
        value1 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
        values2 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: How long does it take if you run the same query manually in your CLI postgres client ? If most of the time is spent in the DB itself, then the answer to your question is nothing specific to Django. Hint: if `time_stamp` is discriminating enough (=> you only have a very small fraction of `mytable` records sharing the same time_stamp value) you may want to index it.

Comment: and i don't sure, that user real need all 2800 string may be you can look on the pagination?

Comment: In the console I have run the same query and I got this `Execution time: 753.086 ms` and my Django Debug Toolbar shows this 1439,04 s.

Comment: console and django application run from the same server? show iscreen from toolbar please.

Comment: Yes, they are run. I edited my question.

Comment: @istvan.hajdu did my answer help you?

Answer (score 3):

Add an [index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/optimization/#use-standard-db-optimization-techniques):

```
class MyTable(models.Model):
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField()
    value1 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    values2 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
         indexes = [
             models.Index(fields=['time_stamp']),
         ]
```

Don't forget to run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` after this.